# Linux, обработка сигнала к потомку

Tags: c++, linux, c, posix, signal

У меня есть сервис для Linux, назовем его `dispatcher`, который запускает другие сервисы (`service`) и всячески их контролирует.

Одной из задач `dispatcher` является установка политики планировщика для каждого `service` (подобно `man chrt`), при этом, для реалтаймовых планировщиков: `rr, fifo`, нужно обрабатывать сигнал `SIGXCPU`, который посылается ядром, когда процесс `service` превысил допустимые лимиты на ресурсы (`man prlimit`). `dispatcher` должен тоже реагировать на этот сигнал и выполнять с проблемным `service` какое-либо действие.
Однако сервисы, через API `dispatcher'а` обрабатывают и другие сигналы.

Есть ли способ поймать этот сигнал, посланный к `service` в `dispatcher`? При этом не навредив логике обработки остальных сигналов?
Я читал про process groups, но это, кажется, не подходит, т.к `services` должны обрабатывать и другие сигналы.

Если и можно сделать это через process groups, то как мне фильтровать сигналы?
`SIGXCPU` должен обрабатывать `dispatcher`, а, например `SIGTERM, SIGHUP` должны оказываться для каждого `service` и для `dispatcher` уместными только для них самих, а не для всей группы процессов.

Comment: Контролировать сигналы, получаемый другим процессом можно посредством ptrace. Хотя сама идея завязываться на сигналы выглядит крайне сомнительной.

Comment: Вас интересует, что делать, если service сам ловит SIGXCPU и продолжает работать? Если он просто игнорирует сигнал, то это можно отследить в  /proc/<PID>/status. Если же сервис ничего не делает, то SIGXCPU  просто его убьет и диспетчер увидит это по wait status